# Installing Ubuntu Server on MacMini Server 5,3

Tags: installation, mac

I've gotten hold of a neat new Mac Mini, i7 processor, 2x500GB hard drives and so on - model MacMini5,3. (from `sysctl hw.model`)

I now want to install Ubuntu Server on it as I am not super comfortable in OS X Server. My problem is that while I can make a bootable install usb (using UNetbootin or usb-creator-gtk) and get to the install menu of it I can't get the installer to start. I am fairly sure that this is due to lack of graphics drivers. I can get the thing to install from a "Mini" install ISO which doesn't have the graphical installer but for some reason that never boots once it's installed.

Is there any way to change the default installer on a regular install ISO to the non-graphical one? I have tried using the "alternate" ISO's but they run into the same problem as the regular ones.

Or can you edit the install command to exclude the graphics?

Comment: The alternate ISO has an option to run in text mode. Somewhere in the Advanced sub-menu.

Answer (score 1):

Never had any luck with the alternate installers but Ubuntu Server 11.10 installs without any problems.

Thanks anyway!

Some bonus things;

Set to autoreboot on power failure: `setpci -s 0:1f.0 0xa4.b=0` (not sticky, put in startup script)

Note that you may also want to run

`sudo apt-get install build-essential`

after a fresh install to get the default compiler/build tools.